# Why function returns None?

Tags: python, class

Why does the **cat1.set_size()** function return **None** instead of **"small"** and the **cat2.color** function returns **"<__ main __. Tiger object at 0x000002711C6D4DF0>"** instead of **"white"**?

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, color, cat_type):
        self.size = "undefined"
        self.color = color
        self.cat_type = cat_type

    def set_size(self, cat_type):
        if self.cat_type == "indoor":
            self.size = "small"
        else:
            pass


class Tiger(Cat):
    def __init__(self, color, cat_type):
        super().__init__(color, cat_type)

    def set_size(self, cat_type):
        super().__init__(self, cat_type)
        if self.cat_type == "wild":
            self.size = "big"
        else:
            self.size = "undefined"


cat1 = Cat(color="black", cat_type="indoor")
cat1_size = cat1.set_size("indoor")
print(cat1.color, cat1.cat_type, cat1_size)

cat2 = Tiger(color="white", cat_type="wild")
cat2.set_size("wild")
print(cat2.color, cat2.cat_type, cat2.size)
```

Conclusion:

```
black indoor None
<__main__.Tiger object at 0x000002711C6D4DF0> wild big
```

Comment: (1) Because you didn't return anything.  If you want it to return the new size, then add `return self.size`.  (2) Because you need to pass `self` to the `super().__init__` function.

Comment: There's no reason for `set_size` to take an argument, because you never look at the argument. Nor is there any reason for `Tiger.set_size` to call `super().set_size`.

Comment: `cat1_size` != `cat1.size`

Comment: `super().__init__(color, cat_type)` needs to be `super().__init__(self, color, cat_type)`

Comment: That function does not contain any `return` statements.  Why would you expect it to return anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better organization.

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, color, cat_type):
        self.size = "undefined"
        self.color = color
        self.cat_type = cat_type

    def set_size(self):
        if self.cat_type == "indoor":
            self.size = "small"

class Tiger(Cat):
    def set_size(self):
        if self.cat_type == "wild":
            self.size = "big"

cat1 = Cat(color="black", cat_type="indoor")
cat1.set_size()
print(cat1.color, cat1.cat_type, cat1.size)

cat2 = Tiger(color="white", cat_type="wild")
cat2.set_size()
print(cat2.color, cat2.cat_type, cat2.size)
```

This still has problems, though.  The size of the cat should not be determined by "wild" or "indoor".  A `Tiger`, as a specific kind of `Cat`, should always have its size set to "big".  You might have another subclass called `Domestic` that has its size set to "small".

Answer (score 1):

It never prints something because you never return anything from the method. You need to return whatever you need at the end of the method.

```
return self.size
```

At the end of set_size method.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no return in the method it always returns None.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. You are not returning anything from `set_size`
2. You are rerunning the `__init__` function in `Tiger`'s `set_size`

Here is the corrected code:

```py
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, color, cat_type):
        self.size = "undefined"
        self.color = color
        self.cat_type = cat_type

    def set_size(self):
        if self.cat_type == "indoor":
            self.size = "small"
        return self.size


class Tiger(Cat):
    def __init__(self, color, cat_type):
        super().__init__(color, cat_type)

    def set_size(self):
        super().set_size()
        if self.cat_type == "wild":
            self.size = "big"
        return self.size


cat1 = Cat(color="black", cat_type="indoor")
cat1_size = cat1.set_size("indoor")
print(cat1.color, cat1.cat_type, cat1_size)

cat2 = Tiger(color="white", cat_type="wild")
cat2.set_size("wild")
print(cat2.color, cat2.cat_type, cat2.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has been slightly modified.

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, color, cat_type):
        self.size = "undefined"
        self.color = color
        self.cat_type = cat_type

    def set_size(self):
        if self.cat_type == 'indoor':
            self.size = 'small'
        return self.size

class Tiger(Cat):
    def __init__(self, color, cat_type):
        super().__init__(color, cat_type)

    def set_size(self):
        super().set_size()
        if (self.cat_type == 'wild'):
            self.size = 'big'
        return self.size


cator = Cat(color='black', cat_type='indoor')

cator_size = cator.set_size()

print("Cat is {}, {}, {}".format(cator.color, cator.cat_type, cator_size))
```